# Testing MPI project (compiling using Cmake) with Travis CI

Tags: c++, cmake, mpi, travis-ci

I am learning to use Travis CI for continuous integration. My project needs to use the MPI library so I let Travis install `OpenMPI` and use `cmake` to compile the code. 
Here is my `.travis.yml` file

```
## configure Travis to use the right compiler
dist: trusty
sudo: false # do not need sudo support
language: cpp

# Cacnhing dependencies
cache:
 directories:
  - openmpi-4.0.2   # build mpi only need to done onece


# MPI project
before_install:
 - sh ./get_openmpi.sh 

# save listing branches (specifies the branch to build) 
branches:
 only:
 - master
 - load_balancing 


script:
 - mkdir build
 - mkdir outputs
 - mkdir tests
 - cd build
 - cmake ..     # configuring cmake in the current build folder
```

And here is my `get_openmpi.sh` script file to intall `OpenMPI`. I install it in `openmpi-4.0.2` directory.

```
#!/bin/sh

# check if OpenMPI is cached from previous build
if [ -f "openmpi/bin/mpirun"]; then
 echo "Using cached OpenMPI"
else
 echo "Downloading OpenMPI source"
 wget https://download.open-mpi.org/release/open-mpi/v4.0/openmpi-4.0.2.tar.gz
 tar xfz openmpi-4.0.2.tar.gz
 rm openmpi-4.0.2.tar.gz
 echo "Configuring and building openmpi"
 cd openmpi-4.0.2
 ./configure --prefix=`pwd`
 make -j 4 all
 make install
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:`pwd`/lib
 cd ..
fi
```

And my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

# name of the project + language
project(2d_wave CXX)

# Bring the headers
include_directories(inc)

# source file
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")

# executable file
add_executable(main ${SOURCES})



# MPI-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# find MPI package
find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
if(MPI_NOFOUND)
    message(ERROR "MPI is not found. Please check FindMPI.")
endif(MPI_NOFOUND)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# libraires links
target_link_libraries(main PUBLIC MPI::MPI_CXX )
```

However, `cmake` cannot find the MPI library by using `find_package()`. I exported library path in my script file (Do I need to do that?), but it did not help.

Can anyone tell me how to link MPI library to cmake? Thanks a lot!

Here is the error info:

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at /usr/local/cmake-3.9.2/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find MPI_CXX (missing: MPI_CXX_LIBRARIES MPI_CXX_INCLUDE_PATH)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/cmake-3.9.2/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:377 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/cmake-3.9.2/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindMPI.cmake:640 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:23 (find_package)
```

If you need more information, you can have a look of my Travis page [here](https://travis-ci.com/ShiqiHe000/DG_wave_c). I want to test my project on brach `load_balancing`.

Comment: does your app require MPI C++ bindings?

Comment: Sorry, what do the MPI C++ bindings mean? It should be compiled as `mpicxx *.cpp -o main` and run as `mpirun -np number main`.

Comment: Do your MPI calls look like `MPI::Init()` or ` MPI_Init()` ?

Comment: I use `MPI_Init()`

Comment: Is `mpicxx` in your `$PATH`? if yes, you can try `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=mpicxx -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=mpicc` and see if it helps.

Comment: I guess this is the problem. So I set `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=mpicxx -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=mpicc` as you suggested. Then I got 
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:
    mpicxx
  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.
  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH. I added `set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /openmpi-4.0.2/bin/mpicxx)` in my `CMakeLists.txt`, but I still gained the same error.

Comment: Why don’t you simply add `mpicxx` to your `$PATH`? (The shell variable, not a CMake variable)

Answer (score 0):

```
if [[ ${TRAVIS_OS_NAME} == "linux" ]]; then
     CMAKE_URL="http://www.cmake.org/files/v3.5/cmake-3.5.1-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz"
     mkdir -p ${DEPS_DIR}/cmake
     travis_retry wget --no-check-certificate --quiet -O - ${CMAKE_URL} | tar --strip- 
     components=1 -xz -C ${DEPS_DIR}/cmake
    export PATH=${DEPS_DIR}/cmake/bin:${PATH} 
fi
```